# Vertical Parallax scrolling in hotdot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, github

I am working on this parallax from git hub https://github.com/htdt/parallax.

The parallax effect is awesome here .I am trying to modify the code.Here the scroll is from right to left.I want a top /down scrolling.I have tried changing the positions(right to top ,left to bottom overflow-Y to overflow -x) ,but its not working .Any idea on how to to that?I would love to learn this one as the effect after the scroll to the element(box/image) is awesome.(It shows a little stirring kind of effect)I dint find it in any other project.Is there any other version (showing top down parallax of htdt)available. Please redirect in that case.

Answer (score 0):

For Vertical Parallax scrolling you can use these other jQuery Plugins:-

http://darsa.in/

https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

and my Personal Favorite

http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

Comment: They are all good but thy dont have the after scroll effect like of htdt.
Anyway Thanks